# How to generate letters for multiple people from a list of names

Tags: list-manipulation, export, string-manipulation

I need to generate many letters of invitation from a list of people. I thought this would be already asked/answered in this forum, but I can't find anything useful. Basically, I need to write a letter of invitation to different people:

1. I have the names of the people whom I'm addressing in a list.
2. The text that is constant for all letters, in text form (Alt+7 in Windows).

Then, I need to export the letter as a PDF using each of the names from the list and the constant text. How can I go about this? I'm open to any general strategy, as I can't find a starting point.

EDIT1: I know how to do basic string manipulation. Here what I mean is to generate an actual letter, so I'd need to export each letter as a PDF with a decent "letter-like" format (it suffices to have the simple formatting that you get with Alt+7 in Windows).

Cheers,

Pedro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you mean something like this?

```
"This is " <> # <> "'s invitation" & /@ {"Alice", "Bob", "Mary"}
```

> {"This is Alice's invitation", "This is Bob's invitation", "This is 
>   Mary's invitation"}

here is a way to export these texts to pdf

```
Export[# <> ".pdf", "This is " <> # <> "'s invitation"] & /@ {"Alice",
"Bob", "Mary"}
```

> {"Alice.pdf", "Bob.pdf", "Mary.pdf"}

This creates a pdf for every name that you can find in your documents folder

Comment: Or `StringTemplate["This is ``'s invitation"] /@ {"Alice", "Bob", "Mary"}`.

Comment: @J42161217 I edited my question to be a bit more explicit. What I meant is to export a document that is formatted as a letter, programmatically. So, I'm thinking about combining the "text form" which is the generic text (Alt+7) and mapping of the list of names, to finally do something like Export["letter.pdf", letter], but I can't see how. Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: @PedroSapichu I added the export function. Now every letter is a pdf named after a name and the text in the pdf uses the same name

Comment: @J42161217 thanks for the edit. It is not exactly what I want, but it is a starting point (which is what I asked for), so I'll accept this as an answer. Thanks again!